# STS plugin not showing

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, plugins

I have installed Spring Tool Suite 4 plugin for eclipse but I have an issue, it is not showing nothing about plugin. I can't create a new Spring project, open perspective, see the Boot Dashboard...

I have installed JDK 1.8.191 and Eclipse IDE 2018‑09.

I tried install Spring Tool Suite 3 but I have the same error.

How I can solve it?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: did you restart after installation?

Comment: @aldr Yes, I did but it didn't work.

Comment: check out the comments https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4 looks like you are not the only one having this issue

Comment: @aldr I just open eclipse with administrator permissions and reinstall the plugin and it works.

Comment: its always the small things good job figuring it out

Answer (score 1):

at [their page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4)  there's a exact q&a post asking the same thing:

> Re: Spring Perspective not showing up (Spring Tool Suite 4...
>
> Submitted by Martin Lippert on Thu, 2018-10-04 09:05
>
> Spring Tools 4 don't contain any Spring perspective anymore, the major elements got added to the regular Java perspective, since that is what most people use for daily Spring Boot app development. So if you open an existing workspace that had the Spring perspective open from STS3 with STS4, you should close that perspective and continue with the Java one instead.